# Add user to groups when creating user in Ion Auth using form_dropdown

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

I add to auth controller in function create_user():

```
if ($this->ion_auth->is_admin())
        {    
            $this->data['groups'] = $this->ion_auth->groups()->result_array(); // выбираем все группы
            $groups=$this->data['groups'];
        } 
...
if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data, $groups)) 
...
```

Next in view I add dropdown field and want to populate it with all groups from table 'groups':

```
<div class="grid_8"><p>Добавить в группы:<br />

    <?php echo form_dropdown('groups',$groups) ?></p></div>
```

but I get mistaked dropdown list:

```
0
    1
    admin
    Administrator
1
    2
    moderator
    Moderator
...
```

Please help me understand how to make good list of all groups:

```
Administrator
Moderator
User
...
```

Comment: What is the result when you `echo print_r($groups);` ?

Comment: Dirk, it shows array in array: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => admin
            [description] => Разработчик
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => admins
            [description] => Администратор
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => moderators
            [description] => Модератор
        )
...
)

Answer (score 0):

I did this in **ion_auth_model.php**

```
/**
 * group list
 *
 * @return array
 * @author Susilo N
 **/
public function grouplist()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('groups');

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                  $listArray[$row->id] = $row->name;                
            }               

    return $listArray;
}
```

then I add this at controller

```
$this->data["listGroups"] = $this->ion_auth->grouplist();
```

and in the view

```
<?= form_dropdown('groups', $listGroups, '1') ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's good if user belongs to only one group, but what about multiple groups? There is no 'groups' field in users table now in Ion Auth. Instead there is 'users_groups' table to assign different users to groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
$group = array('1'); // Sets user to admin if 1  or whatever values received from form dropdown.

$this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data, $group)
```