# Blank Group When Registering From Post in Ion Auth Library

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth, registering

I followed **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098339/add-user-to-groups-when-creating-user-in-ion-auth-using-form-dropdown)** one.

and followed the documentation too: **[Link1](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#register)** and **[Link2](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#groups)**

```
 $group = array();
            $groups = $this->ion_auth->groups()->result();
            foreach ($groups as $gr)
            {
                $group[$gr->id] = $gr->name;
            }
            // ----------------
            $data['group'] = $group;
```

2 of there is same to produce 'groups' in tables, but I have some problem when I submit data from post form, I get blank groups in table, and some times show the warning in:

```
in line 833 ion_auth_model.php
```

Please give me a shoot 'right' code when registering, I am confused with this  one.

Comment: add ur view and register controller to the question